# How to expose HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors into ClearScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html-agility-pack, clearscript

Context: Azure, C#, [ClearScript](https://clearscript.codeplex.com), JavaScript, [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com), [HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors](https://github.com/hcesar/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelector)

I do this a lot: add scripting to C# apps using ClearScript. Ordinarily this just works.

```
...
using Microsoft.ClearScript;
using Microsoft.ClearScript.Windows;
...
    class Program
    {
        static JScriptEngine JSengine = null;
...
                    JSengine = new JScriptEngine(WindowsScriptEngineFlags.EnableDebugging | WindowsScriptEngineFlags.EnableJITDebugging);
....
                    JSengine.AddHostType("CSHtmlDocument", typeof(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument));
...
```

and then later, in the JavaScript code itself, there are things like

```
...
var hap = new CSHtmlDocument();
hap.LoadHtml(html);
...
```

So this is going really well until I add `HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors` into the mix. On the C# side, this adds extra methods to the `HtmlDocument` object, specifically `QuerySelector` and `QuerySelectorAll`. They're visible on the C# side. However, on the JavaScript side they're not and code such as

```
...
var selection = hap.QuerySelector(".reduced");
...
```

throws an error and looking at the object from a debugging session in Visual Studio 2015 shows no `QuerySelector` method in the hap var.

So what's the story? Is it a ClearScript issue or a C# issue? And what do I do about it? I'm quite happy to write a wrapper class, I was just expecting everything to work as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These new methods are most likely [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) defined by a particular class. To make them accessible from script code, you must expose that class to the script engine.

EDIT: I'm not familiar with them, but it looks like the methods you're talking about are provided by the [`HapCssExtensionMethods`](https://github.com/hcesar/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelector/blob/8c19023548eab3567c6cbef1ebb01bb97e2bac40/HapCss/ExtensionMethods.cs) class (or something very similar). To expose the methods, simply expose the class:

```
// C#
JSengine.AddHostType(typeof(HapCssExtensionMethods));
```

Once you've done that, your JavaScript sample above should work as is.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the syntax?

Comment: Ok, that compiles. About to see whether it works on the scripting side.

Comment: We have a winner. Thank you very much indeed!